# Why the RetainedFragment's method 'setData()' load data from web on main thread?

Tags: android

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes.html

```
    // find the retained fragment on activity restarts
    FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
    dataFragment = (DataFragment) fm.findFragmentByTag(“data”);

    // create the fragment and data the first time
    if (dataFragment == null) {
        // add the fragment
        dataFragment = new DataFragment();
        fm.beginTransaction().add(dataFragment, “data”).commit();
        // load the data from the web
        dataFragment.setData(loadMyData());
    }

    // the data is available in dataFragment.getData()



How to use the method "loadMyData()"? thanks.
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding data, before adding the fragment itself.

```
 // create the fragment and data the first time
    if (dataFragment == null) {
        // add the fragment
        dataFragment = new DataFragment();
        // load the data from the web
        dataFragment.setData(loadMyData());
        fm.beginTransaction().add(dataFragment, “data”).commit();
    }
```

You edited your question, but according to your previous question:

This is because `StrictMode` does not allow you to use network connections on the main thread. You can simply fix this by using an `AsyncTask`, but creating a new `Thread` can also fix your problem.

```
    FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
    dataFragment = (DataFragment) fm.findFragmentByTag(“data”);

    if (dataFragment == null) {
        dataFragment = new DataFragment();
        fm.beginTransaction().add(dataFragment, “data”).commit();
        Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                dataFragment.setData(loadMyData());
            }
        });
        thread.start();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This article talk about how to return object after run time changes happened like orientation .. etc

First in activity that hold this fragment onCreate will called

he find fragment and attached it again with data , loadMyData() here means get data you want pass to fragment from (web service , database ... etc )

and finally  data will be in fragment , do what ever you want with it

```
// data object we want to retain
    private MyDataObject data;
```

activity

// find the retained fragment on activity restarts
        FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
        dataFragment = (DataFragment) fm.findFragmentByTag(“data”);

```
    // create the fragment and data the first time
    if (dataFragment == null) {
        // add the fragment
        dataFragment = new DataFragment();
        fm.beginTransaction().add(dataFragment, “data”).commit();
        // load the data from the web
        dataFragment.setData(loadMyData());
    }

    // the data is available in dataFragment.getData()
```